# error clone repositary in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe ls-remote -h hkk_git@10.122.222.122:dinc-chat-server.git HEAD" returned status code 128: stdout:  stderr: Host key verification failed.  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The error message is pretty clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the ssh protocol. Which means u need to add the public key of Jenkins into Git.

Otgerwise u can use the http protocol for cloning via password